# How long a phonocardiography (PCG) should be for diagnosis?

Tags: measurement, heart

I have many PCG records with different lengths, what is the minimum length (minutes or seconds) that a specialist use to diagnose any abnormalities in heart?

Highly appreciate your help.
Cheers

Answer (score -1):

There is no fixed lenght for PCG.
Usually is made paired with an ECG, in order to correlate electro and mechanic activity to sound activity.

Sounds in this case, come from the valves (1st and 2nd tone), so looking at a complete cardiac cicle it should be clear if the subject has a particular severe condition.

In the case the condition is not severe, more cardiac cycles can be useful, but the decision to record for minutes or seconds is personal. Usually longer records are made to take more data to analyze, but if you have a patology, you have it in quite every cardiac cycle.

In addition to this, nowadays, a PCG is less used as a time, because a simple auscultation can show you the same result as a PCG. It is useful for storing data during long time.

---

Ref.

I've not many references, but only my personal experience. You can check any cardiologic and diagnosys book. If I find relevant references, I'll edit the post.

Comment: -1: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].

Comment: [cont'd]: *If you don't have references, then don't answer the question*